# Typescript array destructuring type

Tags: typescript, destructuring

How should I type following destructured array?

```
const [first, ...rest] = this.employee.roles;
```

The code above works, but project rules impose const typing.

I tried:

```
const first: Role;
const rest: Array<Role>;
[first, ...rest] = this.employee.roles;
```

but then I need to change const to let for `[first, ...rest] = this.employee.roles;`
to work

Following code also works, but isn't it misleading?

```
const [first, ...rest]: Array<Role> = this.employee.roles;
```

since `first` is `Role` and `rest` is `Array<Role>` I'm not sure about this one.

I'd like something similar to this:

```
const [first, ...rest]: [first: Role, rest: Array<Role>] = this.employee.roles;
```

but it's not compiling.

Is there a clean way of typing this or should I just switch to

```
let first: Role;
let rest: Array<Role>;
[first, ...rest] = this.employee.roles;
```

Comment: i think your first idea is correct: `const [first, ...rest]: Array<Role> = this.employee.roles;` (try console logging `[first, ...rest]` out)

Comment: if `this.employee.roles` is already typed, the type of `first` and `rest` should be inferred correctly. if you really need to specify it, this `const [first, ...rest]: Array<Role> = this.employee.roles;` looks correct to me aswell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just use `onst [first, ...rest]: Array<Role>`. If you want you can type is with tuple types, but you will have to make `first` optional, since there is no guarantee `Role[]` will contain any elements, it could be empty:

```
const [first, ...rest]: [first?: Role, ...rest: Array<Role>] = roles;
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEoHsA2KDeyRwC2EAXMgM5hSgDmyAvgLABQAJhApnFCtmMlCwRyZDNgDaAXRYJ0ISsnExgUSgBpkAOm09KkskpWUA-KKEbtm3WDIBBKFDgBPADxiIAPknIAvAKHkANxAA)